# Convert geometries to feature collections on Greenplum with PostGIs extension

Tags: postgis, greenplum

I am new to Greenplum. I used to work on PostgreSQL with PostGIS extension.
Right now I foudnd out that there is no `row_to_json` function in Greenplum. Is there any function that is similar to this one? I have to use this function to convert geometries to Feature Collection.

Answer (score 0):

JSON is not a supported datatype in Greenplum.

Here is the current guide on using postGIS in Greenplum: http://gpdb.docs.pivotal.io/4340/ref_guide/postGIS.html